# How do Singletons work in ASP and COM combination

Tags: c++, asp.net, .net, com

We have a Web application deployed in an IIS Server. The job of this application is to accept request in XML format, extract data, process it and send the response in XML format back to the client.
It is a legacy code with C++ version being from the last century. So C++11 does not work.

Basic architecture is that the Request comes to the ASP file. There is a Server.CreateObject method called to create an Object of the C++ COM. The subsequent methods are called.

In a multithreaded environment, I have the following question.

1. Does the Server.CreateObject create a separate COM object for each request
2. If not, in the C++ code if I have a Singleton object with some necessary global variables(one of which could change with every request) how do I manage this singleton
3. Can there be a object of this singleton per session id, we get the session id from the ASP. If so, how do I create it and how do I access this (map?) elsewhere in the application?

Please add more information. My experience in this is very very limited and would appreciate all the help I can get.

Thank you

Comment: Server.CreateObject creates a new object for each request.

Comment: Are you sure this is ASP.NET? Sounds more like classic ASP (which isn't .NET). What are the file extensions for the pages: is it .asp, or is it .aspx?

Comment: its .asp. I am not sure if it comes in the ambit of .NET.

Comment: Simon Mourier - If I create a Singleton in the C++ code, will it be created per request or will it remain global for all thread. My requirement is that I need an object which can store global values in the entire context of the thread.

Comment: Server.CreateObject will indirectly call COM's CoCreateInstance, your class factory, etc.. What happens behind depends on your implementation. You can use a C++ singleton behind the scene. Keeping one object for all threads means you'll have to write synchronization (multithreaded-safe) code. Not sure what you means by "global value in the context of the thread". Seems contradictory.

Comment: There is some data which is unique per request. I want to access it anytime I want. So that's why we created a singleton. But is it possible to store this unique data per thread/request and have it access it anywhere in the codebase

Comment: An ASP "classic" request  executes in one thread. So you don't need a singleton if you want to keep some variable associated with the instance that was created by Server.CreateObject. eg: `set o = Server.CreateObject("blah"), o.Value = "blih", Response.Output o.Value` should work fine w/o any singleton